# What does sleeping do in WASTED?

Tags: wasted

After sleeping I've noticed there is a rested effect on me, but apart from keeping me from sleeping again, I don't see any other effect.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sleeping advances time. Other than that, it has no effect.

The developer answered a similar question on the Steam forums [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/327510/discussions/0/357288572119360941/). The buzz just prevents you from sleeping again immediately.

> Its just a mechanism to prevent players from exploiting the time advance to trivialize the timers on some of the house upgrades